# Coding a smart contract for people to easily start a trustless bet online. How to improve my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, metamask, oracles

so I really want to create a smart contract for the community to use - one where two people can easily and trustlessly make a bet between each other. V1 of the smart contract would be where two people (or more) bet that cryptocurrency pair X will reach the price of Y by a certain date Q. Once the condition is met, the funds are released to the winner.

It is one of my first smart contracts, I appreciate any help I can get.
I know it is far from finished, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction?
Would be greatly appreciated. I have a cool and useful product in mind :)

Once the Betting contract is finished, I will want to hook it up with Chainlink decentralized oracle to provide data to the blockchain. Oh, and I would like the dApp to run on Matic.

Where can I learn to do it? I've been watching videos and trying, but I think I reached a point where I can learn further only by trying to do it myself.

'''

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

contract Betting {

enum State { Created, Locked, Released }

struct Bet {

string pair;

uint price;

uint date;
}

event BetMade(address bettor, uint amount);

function bet() public payable {

    emit BetMade(msg.sender, msg.value);

}



}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Once you're ready to obtain external price data, be sure to check out the [Chainlink doc](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/)s on how to do this, it's super easy!

I know this isn't a hackathon submission, but we also have a great [hackathon resources](https://docs.chain.link/docs/hackathon-resources/) page with some links that could be useful to you as part of your learning journey